# Pass a value from ASP.NET controller to CSS

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I'm not sure whether it's possible or not in my way. But I need it.

I have a css rule to define home page background image in `style.css`.
I would like to randomly select an image from a directory. Images names are like `main-bg-*.jpg` (i.e. main-bg-1.jpg, main-bg-2.jpg).

CSS

```
#background-div {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
color: #000;
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: -1;
background-image: url('../Images/Backgrounds/home-page-bg-1.jpg');
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
background-color: #464646;
-webkit-filter: blur(5px);
-moz-filter: blur(5px);
-o-filter: blur(5px);
-ms-filter: blur(5px);
filter: blur(5px);
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
   <div id="background-div"></div>
   -------
   -------
</body>
```

I want to generate a number between 1 to 10 in controller method, then pass it to the css rule.

How can i do it?

If there is any other convenient way, please let me know.

Sorry if this is a silly question.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not doing it from JS. You can access background DOM element and update with random number for images

Comment: @qamar, If it can be done in js, i have no problem. Would you please show an example?

Comment: can you paste your css for background image so that I can work out an example for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you can do something like following to set background image from JS.

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(your image url)';
```

Answer (score 2):

JS:

```
var img = 'main-bg-'+ Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1)+'.jpg';
 document.getElementById('elementid').style.backgroundImage = url(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this in C# and CSS is to add a class to the div aswell as using the ID:

```
<body>
   <div id="background-div" class="background1"></div>
   -------
   -------
</body>
```

and setting up the 10 classes in CSS:

```
.background1 { background-image: url('../Images/Backgrounds/home-page-bg-1.jpg'); } 

...

.background10 { background-image: url('../Images/Backgrounds/home-page-bg-10.jpg'); }
```

I know you already selected an answer, just suggesting as a way to do what you requested without the requirement for javascript